# How do I display a tiled map in Pygame using Tiled and pytmx?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, tiled

I'm aware there is a similar question but the answers were not specific enough to be useful in my case.

I am trying to create a program that can display a tiled map created in Tiled and uploaded into Pygame using pytmx. The only issue I'm having is blitting the images onto the screen in Pygame.

This is the error I keep receiving:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\b\Desktop\Frozen Map Textures\test.py", line 32, in 
    screen.blit(images[i],(x*32,y*32))
    TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None

If anybody knows how to fix the issue is, I would be very grateful! Thanks for all your  help!

The code is below:

```
import pygame
from pytmx import load_pygame
import random


white = (255,255,255)


#create window
screenSize = (800,600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screenSize)
pygame.display.set_caption("GameName")
screen.fill(white)


gameMap = load_pygame("Frozen.tmx")


#creates list of single tiles in first layer
images = []
for y in range(50):
    for x in range(50):
        image = gameMap.get_tile_image(x,y,0)
        images.append(image)


#displays tiles in locations
i = 0
for y in range(50):
    for x in range(50):
        screen.blit(images[i],(x*32,y*32))
        i += 1


#main loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: By the way, I am running on 64 bit Windows 8. I'm not sure if that will make a difference for anything.

Comment: Please could you tell us what happens when you try to blit.

Comment: I will. I haven't been able to try it out. I had to leave town before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with pytmx, but I think the problem is that variable `i` runs from `0` to `2600`  in the first `for`-loop (you have 2600 items / images / tiles in the `images` list). But when you create the list of tile locations (`imageLocs`), `i` only runs from `0` to `49`, so you have a list `50` different locations.

This means you don´t have "enough" locations for each tile.

In addition to that you don´t need to increment any variables in a `for i in rang(value)`-loop in python, because `i` runs throw (i.e. gets assigned to) all values the `range()` function returns.

You could update your code to avoid this problem:

```
#Original code    

#create a list of 2600 single tiles in first layer
images = []

for y in range(50):
    for x in range(50):
        image = gameMap.get_tile_image(x,y,0)
        images.append(image)

#blit all tiles onto the screen
i = 0 #runs from 0 to 2600

for y in range(50):
    for x in range(50):
        screen.blit(images[i],(x * 32, y * 32))
        i += 1

#Orginal code
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I updated my code and added the error message I was receiving also. Do you know what the issue is? I just can't find why the list index is providing type None.

Comment: Hey! Just ignore my last comment. It turned out there was a single blank space in my map file.... Thanks for all your time! Your suggestions really made my code look nice!

Comment: i think i is 0 to 2500 (i.e. 50 * 50)